# How to start text in a complete new 'row' when text paragraphs and images float and aligned?

Tags: html, css

Yes I know the title is a bit cloudy, so anyone have better idea please edit.

However I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dLutg6L/1/) to make clear what I would like to do.

I have a most simplest mixed texts and images content. What I would like to achieve is the second text and second image should go to a complete new row, just below the line when image 1 (and its title) bottom line.

I've tried "clearfix" ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dLutg6L/1/)) with no success:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Obviously I am missing something simple because of my beginner level css/html skills.

Comment: You could clear like this https://jsfiddle.net/5dLutg6L/2/

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely an answer.

Comment: Don't use curly quotes. `br` elements don't support `::after`.

Comment: @NenadVracar: In case you submit this as answer I am going to accept it...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to post an answer to address the misinformation posted in other answer.

First, your `.clearfix` selector does not select your `br` because you use `”` instead of `"`:

```
<br class=”clearfix” />
```

Since in HTML attribute values are not required to be enclosed by `"` if they don't contain whitespace, your markup is equivalent to

```
<br class="”clearfix”" />
```

Second, `br` elements are void elements. They can't have content. The `::after` pseudo-element inserts content inside (at the end) of an element. So using `::after` on void elements won't work.

If you want to use this clearfix, use a non-void element, e.g. `div`.

That should work. However, clearfix is not intended to be used like this. Clearfix is applied to a wrapper which contains floats in order to make it grow to enclose the floats.

But in this case you only want to clear a float, so just use `clear`.

Comment: Thanks for the details. (And that copy and paste error about quotation mark is a shame.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the height of the `<p>` tag in your css file.

```
p {height: 218px;}
```